# Как установить libuv в ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, qtcreator, lib

Увы не получается установить в Ubuntu  библиотеку libuv

```
comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-get install libuv
[sudo] пароль для comp: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет libuv
```

Подумал что можно в QtCreator-е через модули подключить.  НО увы модуля такого нету ;_;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем надо было использовать команду  `sudo apt-cache search название_библиотеки`

**в водим команду**

```
comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-cache search libuv
libuv1 - asynchronous event notification library - runtime library
libuv1-dev - asynchronous event notification library - development files
python3-uvloop - fast implementation of asyncio event loop on top of libuv
python3-uvloop-dbg - fast implementation of asyncio event loop on top of libuv
libh2o-dev - dev helpers of the H2O library compiled with libuv
libh2o0.13 - H2O library compiled with libuv
libuv0.10 - asynchronous event notification library - runtime library
libuv0.10-dbg - asynchronous event notification library - debugging symbols
libuv0.10-dev - asynchronous event notification library - development files
libuvc-dev - cross-platform library for USB video devices - development files
libuvc-doc - cross-platform library for USB video devices - documentation
libuvc0 - cross-platform library for USB video devices
lua-luv - libuv bindings for lua
lua-luv-dev - libuv bindings for lua
node-errno - libuv errno details exposed - Node.js module
r-cran-httpuv - GNU R package of HTTP and WebSocket Server Library
```

**Ага, называется "она" не `libuv`, а `libuv1` это во первых, а во вторых мне нужен не только `libuv1` но `libuv1-dev`.**

на всякий "пожарный" обновляю

```
comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-get update
Сущ:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Сущ:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Сущ:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Пол:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
Пол:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24,1 kB]
Пол:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [10,4 kB]
Пол:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [31,7 kB]
Пол:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [565 kB]
Пол:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [572 kB]
Пол:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [186 kB]
Пол:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41,2 kB]
Пол:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16,4 kB]
Пол:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [111 kB]
Пол:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]
Получено 1 649 kB за 2с (948 kB/s)                                  
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
```

**Устанавливаем `libuv1`**

```
comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-get install libuv1
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет libuv1 самой новой версии (1.18.0-3).
libuv1 помечен как установленный вручную.
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  libllvm7 libllvm7:i386
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 23 пакетов не обновлено.
```

**Ага, оказывается библиотека установлена, не установлена библиотека разработчика.**

```
 comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-get install libuv1-dev
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  libllvm7 libllvm7:i386
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  libuv1-dev
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 23 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 82,0 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 401 kB.
Пол:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libuv1-dev amd64 1.18.0-3 [82,0 kB]
Получено 82,0 kB за 0с (548 kB/s)     
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libuv1-dev:amd64.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 305956 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/libuv1-dev_1.18.0-3_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается libuv1-dev:amd64 (1.18.0-3) …
Настраивается пакет libuv1-dev:amd64 (1.18.0-3) …
```

---

Вот код с простейшей программой с использование библиотеки `libuv`

**lib_example.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.c

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -luv

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>

int main()
{
    uv_loop_t *loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
    uv_loop_init(loop);

    printf("Now quitting.\n");
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);
    return 0;
}
```

выводит

```
Now quitting.
Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...
```